# How to calculate resolution of radar?

Tags: radar

I am working of FMCW radar. Below are all the parameters of FMCW radar. How can I Calculate the resolution of my radar

```
Parameters            Values
Center frequency (fc)     70GHz
Bandwidth (BW)            40 GHz
Sampling frequency (fs)   10 MHz
Sweep time            0.2 ms
Number of periods    10 period
```

Comment: Did you have success in your range design?
I would like to design the same unless you would share.
Please email grues1234@yahoo.com Subject "Range Finder"
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The range resolution is normally some fraction bandwidth of the pulse. The fraction will depend on how you measure it i.e. null to null, 3dB points, 6 dB points etc. Also the windowing (Hamming, Kaiser) used will reduce the resolution i.e. increase the number. For a chirp pulse with the bandwidth you stated the null to null width is given by

$$ \delta r = \frac{c}{2BW}=\frac{3\cdot 10^8}{2\cdot  40\cdot 10^9 }=3.75 \cdot 10^{-3} \textrm{ m } $$

You can reference the following links:

- [High Range Resolution Techniques](http://www.acfr.usyd.edu.au/pdfs/training/sensorSystems/11%20High%20Range-Resolution%20Techniques.pdf)
- [Understanding Millimetre Wave FMCW Radars](http://www-ist.massey.ac.nz/conferences/icst05/proceedings/icst2005-papers/icst_111.pdf),
- [Radar Basics](http://www.radartutorial.eu/01.basics/Range%20Resolution.en.html)

Comment: That 'e' has to be changed to 10.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question, but there's also angular resolution, or the width of the mainlobe of your radar. This can sometimes be referred to as cross range resolution, and there are many [approximations](http://www.satsig.net/pointing/antenna-beamwidth-calculator.htm) you can use based on the type of radiator you're using.

There's also sampling resolution, which is similarly calculated as the range resolution, but defines the spacing between samples. Whereas the range resolution defines the minimum detection distance between two point targets.